# 9-Patch, Border around Image button

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, dynamic, nine-patch

I am trying to apply many picture/photo/avatar user icons (dynamically) so as a user signs up a new button will be added.  I want each button to be surrounded by a polaroid frame.  Im guessing this is a 9-patch thing (never used before).  I have created the 9-patch with transparent centre, but I have no idea how to surround each image button with the polaroid border.  I managed to dynamically program a layout before and that should be no problem.  I am trying to practice surrounding the button in xml at the moment..but nay such luck! please can someone help me! can it even be done?am i going in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Whey I did it.  Quite easy but if you've never done it, it is hard to know each settings element to go with.  Here's my answer

```
 </LinearLayout>

    <ImageButton

        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:maxHeight="600dp"
        android:maxWidth="300dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@drawable/events_selected"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:background="@drawable/photo_4"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

I will post dynamic code when done